# Cannot find table 0 for ExecuteDataSet in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting exception for

```
DataTable ProbRead = SQLData.ExecuteDataSet("SELECT description FROM chk_maintenance_probremark where subheaderid = " + lblrefno.Text.ToString() + " and Type='Problem'").Tables[0];
```

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Easy. You have no table[0].Maybe you need a `'` before and after `" + lblrefno.Text.ToString() + "`depending on the type of `subheaderid`. That's one of the problems of not using parametrized queries

Comment: @Pikoh Got Yaa.. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

seems your sql query does not have a result 
try this

```
var probRead = SQLData.ExecuteDataSet("SELECT description FROM chk_maintenance_probremark where subheaderid = " + lblrefno.Text.ToString() + " and Type='Problem'");
if(probRead.Tables.Count > 0)
{
  var myTable = probRead.Tables[0];
 // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the query *readable*:

```
//TODO: get rid of hardcoding, but paramterize the query
//DONE: ToString() is redundant in lblrefno.Text
string sql = 
  $@"select Description
       from Chk_Maintenance_ProbRemark
      where SubHeaderId = '{lblrefno.Text}' and
            Type = 'Problem'";
```

and you'll see the problem clearly: `lblrefno.Text.ToString()` should be wrapped with `'`.

Do not forget to test if you have any data returned:

```
var probRead = SQLData.ExecuteDataSet(sql);

if (probRead.Tables.Count > 0) {
  // It's safe now to call probRead.Tables[0]
  ...
}
```